# What is SQLite3 Disk I/O Error in Cocoa

Tags: sqlite, io, disk

I am programming in snow Leopard 10.6. My application opens up a locally stored database successfully, but when it tries to insert into the database, I continue to receive 
'Disk I/O error". Anyone has any ideas as to what could possibly cause this?

Thanks
Yang

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html):

> SQLITE_IOERR
>
> > This value is returned if the operating system informs SQLite that it is unable to perform
> >     some disk I/O operation. This could mean that there is no more space left on the disk.

This could be one reason. Another could be insufficient rights (maybe the db-file is write protected?).

Comment: how can i check to see if the proper right to manage the file? because the database that i'm testing with is only 4kb.

I tried to include   
chmod(filename, (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR) | (S_IRGRP|S_IWGRP) | (S_IROTH|S_IWOTH));

but I get an error that says chmod is not defined